# How to stop playback after a certain measure in Musescore?

Tags: notation, sheet-music, musescore

Often when I arrange, I include a jam part where I just use the chord notes. I prefer to have this these sections after everything. See picture:

[image]

The problem is when I listen to it on my computer. I would like to skip both sections marked with "Jam". How do I do that?

I tagged with "notation", but I would happily accept a solution that is not based on formal notation, but instead some feature in Musescore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MuseScore is now at v2.3.2.   There seems no excuse for not having the latest version!  But I don't think DS jumps and the like are a VERY new feature.

You can cheat MuseScore into skipping up to two sections of a score in playback.

Playback only halts at 'Fine' when it is coupled with a 'DC al Fine' or 'DS al Fine' instruction.

'DS' normally skips back.  But MuseScore is happy for a 'DS' to skip forward as well.   So we can place 'DS al Coda' at the beginning of a section to be skipped, '$' at the point to continue playing, then 'To Coda' and the Coda symbol to mark another skipped section.  If you only want to skip one section, just.use 'DS' and '$'

These objects can be made invisible in the Inspector if desired. In the example, all the low F notes play, all the high F notes are skipped.

[image]

(Note to users of pre-2.2 versions of MuseScore. Earlier versions followed the 'no repeats after a DS' convention. A repeated section after the jump won't repeat.  After 2.2 we became able to choose.)

[image]

Comment: This worked amazingly. Thank you very much. And yes, I know I should have a newer version, but I'm using Debian Linux, and it can be a bit of a hassle to upgrade individual programs.

Comment: Interesting that the answer that DOESN'T work still has more votes.  Gotta love Stack Exchange!

Comment: It's a matter of speed. :)

Comment: But one thing. This worked. I put a D.S. at 75 and $ at 76. That made the repeat at measure 100 stop working. Same thing happened when I used the whole D.S. al Coda. Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: Looks like you'll need to get to v2.2 or above.  Earlier MuseScore followed the 'no repeats after a DS' convention.  See the addition to my main answer.

Comment: Well, it did repeat when I posted it online and that's good enough for me. If anyone is interested in what you have helped me with, you can listen to it here: https://musescore.com/user/12760656/scores/5191357

Comment: Nice score!   But the first section is clearly in 3/2 rather than 6/4.  Then, when the same beat continues but two-in-a-bar, 2/2 would be clearer than 4/4.

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean that just the B-section should be 2/2 or C too?

Comment: Ideally,  I'd start in  3/4, then 2/4 at B (and C), cut time at D for the fast swing.

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure your Musescore is up to date.

If you place a *fine* in the score from the palette, it should stop playback there. Then you can make it invisible.

And this seems easy once you read it: to skip over measures, place invisible D.C.s and segnos and/or *to coda* and coda marks.

If it's not behaving as expected, check that Musescore is up to date and also check the inspector for each element for a "play" checkbox. Make sure it is checked. There might also be special element properties that control playback that might have to be edited or verified.

Comment: Hmmm, the playback continues, but on the other hand Musescore is quite buggy and it is likely that it would work with a newer version.

Comment: @klutt Definitely check your version. One site I read said at least 1.4 to make playback stop on *fine*. I confess I haven't tried this myself.

Comment: Well, then it's some kind of bug. My version is 2.0.3

Comment: Sorry for accepting and unaccepting, but Paynes answer did actually work for me.

Comment: @klutt Not at all a problem. No need to apologize. That’s why the system works the way it does. I’m glad you got it sorted!